# How to Create a table with merger and resize function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to Create the table with merger and resize function. Both of these two functions, just look like **google spreadsheets**

First, I found merger function by Javascript library

After, Use this code to resize TD `$('td').resizable();` But something wrong.

This table Complete the merge after run resizable function.

```
<table id="BA1"><caption></caption><thead></thead><tbody><tr><td><div class="iitem">+</div></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td colspan="1"rowspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="4"rowspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"rowspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The operation is very convenient, TD after the merger height is limited.

I do not know why? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you already included the JQuery UI and CSS libraries required  such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Preferably, you need also to call your resizable as below.

```
$( function() {
    $('td').resizable();
  } );
```